# FixedHeader and fixed menu bar

Tags: html, css

I've been tinkering with this too long now, so I put out the questions here. I'm trying to have a menu bar on top of a web page. The problem with my approach is that the content page gets scrolled 'behind' the menu bar which causes problems for [DataTable/FixedHeader](http://www.datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/). Instead of stopping the header of the table at the menu, it scrolls into the menu and locks at the top of the screen.[image].

The css looks like this

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}


#content {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    position: static;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to stop the table scrolling all the way up and the header stopping below the menu?

Comment: remove `position: fixed;` or change `top:0`..?

Comment: the property is "margin-top", not "top-margin", you can also try "padding-top" and see if that helps

Comment: @arieljuod: Good catch, but this didn't do it.

Comment: @popnoodles: If I do this, the menu won't be static any more and scroll.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle so we can play with the actual code? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't quite work (sorry I haven't used it before), but essentially I used the example from the demo page and added a placeholder for the menu bar. http://jsfiddle.net/EERV3/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might find your answer in the documentation of DataTable/FixedHeader. As you can see here, you can [specify the following](http://www.datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/options):

> **offsetTop** Specify an offset from the top of the window where the fixed header where be locked to when scrolling. This is useful for
>   working with fixed elements at the top of the page - for example the
>   Twitter Bootstrap fixed menu.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    new FixedHeader( table, {
        "offsetTop": 40
    } );
} );
```

Change the `offsetTop` to the height of your menu bar (50), and you should be all set!

Additionally, you could also add a big `z-index` to the `#header` to ensure it stays "on top" of other elements.

```
#header {
    z-index: 9999;
    /* And your other properties here */
}
```

Comment: Interesting. For some reason, this doesn't work for me. The demo from this description doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Never mind. It works. Not sure what went wrong initially. Thanks for your help.